# How to solve no suitable method found for put(String,long)

Tags: java, android, string, long-integer

Can someone help me to solve this ? I'm trying to send data from android to MySQL using code below but I get `error long cannot converted to String`. I can find plenty of solution related to  `no suitable method found .put(String)` but not in my case, so I decided to seek help from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public void addWorkForce(final String subcontractors, final String noPeople, final String noHours,final long twf)
    {
        class AddWorkForce extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(WorkDetailsTable.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put(Config.KEY_SUBCONTRACTORS,subcontractors);
                data.put(Config.KEY_NUMBERPERSONS,noPeople);
                data.put(Config.KEY_NUMBERHOURS,noHours);
                data.put(Config.KEY_TWF,twf);
                RequestHandler rh=new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.ADD_WORKFORCE,data);
                return  result;
            }
        }

        AddWorkForce ru = new AddWorkForce();
        ru.execute(subcontractors,noPeople,noHours,twf);
    }
```

**Error**

```
Error:(281, 21) error: no suitable method found for put(String,long)
method AbstractMap.put(String,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; long cannot be converted to String)
method HashMap.put(String,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; long cannot be converted to String)
```

Comment: you are using String where Long is expected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079429/error-no-suitable-method-found-for-putstring-int

Comment: dear@Seng u are putting long value in string use data.put(Config.KEY_TWF,Strig.valueof(twf)); like this, it will work for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HashMap` is `<String, String>` means it awaits for `String` key and `String` value. You can change the `HashMap` to `<String, Long>` or convert your `long` value to `String` with method:

```
String.valueOf(long);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
data.put(Config.KEY_TWF,String.valueOf(twf));
```

Answer (score 1):

By passing the correct type of parameters. Your class only has that method with two Strings as a parameter, while you try to call it with a String and a long.

Either change the method in the original type to take a long instead (which is a bad idea, since you might break other code doing so.

Or, add a new method that takes a String and a long as parameters.

Or: call it like this:

Instead of

```
long l = 2L;
callMethod("String", l);
```

do this

```
callMethod("String", String.valueOf(l));
```